# Create new interface B by omitting all properties from interface A by value condition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say I have:

```
Interface A{
  a: number
  b: boolean
  c: string
}
```

and I want to create a new Type B
that contains all of the properties of A that are not of value boolean.
so that the result would be

```
type B = {a: number, c: string}
```

Can anyone think of a way of currently doing it in Typescript today?

I've tried conditional types and mapping over properties, but the conditions don't occur on the
property level.
one of the things i've tried was:

```
type NoneFuncProps<T,K extends keyof T> = { [P in (T[K] extends Function? never: K)]: T[P] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok with a little more fiddling I've managed to find the solution.

```
type NoneFuncProps<T,K extends keyof T = keyof T> = 
{ [P in (K extends any? T[K] extends Function? never: K : K )]: T[P] }
```

What I believe is happening here is when `extends` gets called it iterates through the union of the values, so once I'm asking if K extends any, K now is a single value, which I used to map T, and ask if T extends Function, and so on.